# Prove that if you divide $10^n$ by $9$ then the remainder is $1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$n=1$ 
Then $\frac{10^1}{9} = \frac{10}{9}$ 
remainder = $1$.

For $n\geq2$, how does you do this?

I want to prove that last digit is always zero, of $10$ raised to power. How do I do that please by induction.

thanks you

Comment: Check out the answer I just posted. I think it will make things much clearer for you.

Comment: Hint:  What number comes just before $10^n$?

Comment: I know! I know! $10^n-1$? Couldn't help myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know (and are allowed to use) modular arithmetic, it's as simple as:

$$10 \equiv 1 \pmod 9 \implies 10^n \equiv 1^n = 1 \pmod 9$$

EDIT: For a proof by induction, you already have the base case. The assumption is that $10^k = 9m + 1$.

So here's the inductive step: $10^{k+1} = 10^k\cdot 10 = (9m+1)\cdot 10 = (9)(10m) + 9 + 1 = 9(10m+1) + 1$

Comment: no we use induction

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$10^n=999...9 +1 \,.$$
.

Answer (score 2):

In case you *don't* have modular arithmetic, there's always

$$ \ 10^n \ - \ 1^n \ \ = \ \ (10 \ - \ 1) \ (10^{n-1} \ + \ 10^{n-2} \cdot 1 \ + \ 10^{n-3} \cdot 1^2 \ + \ \ldots \ + \ 10 \cdot 1^{n-2} \ + \ 1^{n-1}) \ \  $$

or

$$ \ 10^n  \ \ = \ \ 1 \ + \ 9 \ (10^{n-1} \ + \ 10^{n-2} \cdot 1 \ + \ 10^{n-3} \cdot 1^2 \ + \ \ldots \ + 10 \cdot 1^{n-2} \ + \ 1^{n-1}) \ \ . $$

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Deepak should be more than enough, but I sense that you are struggling to see how induction really fits in here. I am going to give a more drawn out answer, but I think it may be clearer for you.

---

**Base case:** We have that $10=9+1$ so this is fine.

**Inductive step:** We want to prove that
$$
S(n) : 10^n = 9\ell+1, r\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
holds for all $n\geq 1$. Fix some $k\geq 1$ and assume that 
$$
S(k) : 10^k = 9\ell+1, \ell\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
holds. We want to show that 
$$
S(k+1) : 10^{k+1} = 9m+1, m\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
follows. Beginning with the left side of $S(k+1)$, 
\begin{align}
10^{k+1} &= 10\cdot 10^k\tag{manipulate}\\[0.5em]
         &= 10\cdot(9\ell+1)\tag{by $S(k)$}\\[0.5em]
         &= 9(10\ell+1)+1\tag{manipulate}\\[0.5em]
         &= 9m+1\tag{$m=10\ell+1$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$}
\end{align}
we see that the right side of $S(k+1)$ follows.

Thus, by mathematical induction, the statement $S(n)$ holds for all $n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have already given the base case. Now assume it works for $n$:
$10^n \equiv 1\pmod{9}$. Multiply both sides by $10$:
$10^{n+1} \equiv 10\pmod{9}$. We also have $10 \equiv 1\pmod{9}$, so therefore $10^{n+1} \equiv 1\pmod{9}$. Induction concludes the proof.